# GWT: Is it possible to draw a circular panel?

Tags: java, gwt, panel

I am trying to create a tag cloud in GWT but should be in circular shape and the tags should be randomly arranged. So I wanted to know if it is possible to make a circular panel? till now, I couldn't find any relevant information about tag clouds in GWT except [this link](https://code.google.com/p/gwt-tagcloud/).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

For circular panel try use HtmlPanel and set styles manually 
http://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/

For random location on page try set it via css
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

Comment: This is the best solution. Alternatively, you can use a canvas.

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you want to do is to place your words in a kind of circle area. Adding css style to your HtmlPanel will not help you to do that. Your text will still be rendered line by line as if the div was a square with HTMLPanel. Try to put some words inside the circle div in Dmitry first example with Chrome dev tools.

I would go for a layout panel as a container. Each of your word will be in separate layout panel. Then you can place your words where you want inside your container using the layout panel methods (SetWidgetTopBottom etc.).

But you will need to code the algorithm that determines the position of your word to match a kind of circle.

You will not find anything easier than this IMO.